# 'docker-compose pull' can't pull image that is pullable by 'docker'

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I execute `docker-compose pull`, I get an ERROR:

```
Pulling web (hubusername/reponame:tag)...
Pulling repository docker.io/hubusername/reponame
ERROR: Error: image hubusername/reponame not found
```

But when I execute: `docker pull hubusername/reponame:tag`

```
tag: Pulling from hubusername/reponame
xxxxxxx: Pulling fs layer
yyyyyyy: Pulling fs layer
```

Version info:

```
docker-compose version: 1.5.1
Docker version 1.11.0, build 4dc5990
```

What do I need to change so docker-compose can also pull the image?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the difference was: docker works fine when ~/.docker/config.json only contains an 'auth' property. docker-compose also needs an 'email' property. After adding the email, docker-compose was also working.

Comment: I am facing this issue too but adding the "email" property didn't work for me.